# validate a .edu or .ac email address

Tags: php, javascript, email-validation

I'm a noob but trying vigorously to simply validate email addresses that only end in ".edu" or ".ac" is there a simple function/script/solution to this seemingly simple problem?  able to use php,javascript or jquery.

Any help would be great thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by validate? Confirm that they end with the given strings? That's easy, but knowing what language you want to use would help. If you are trying to "validate" that the mail address can be mailed to, that cannot be done textually; sending mail to an address is the only accurate test for a sendable address.

Comment: @msw - you can validate that an e-mail address is in the required format, i.e. ends in .edu, .ac, contains an @ symbol and only contains the characters defined as valid in RFC 2822.  Even sending to an e-mail address doesn't validate that it actually exists, I've known some badly-configured mail servers to just swallow invalid mail rather than bouncing it.

Comment: @Andy - point taken regarding the "swallowing", thanks. Agreed about the 2822 conformance checking, if only more sites did so accurately says my.address+label@gmail.com. The link to http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html below is pleasingly instructive and has the proper caveats.

Comment: @msw - that site has helped me out tremendously.  IIRC Hotmail servers used to swallow mail - if the mailbox existed but the e-mail couldn't be sent (over-quota, inactive etc) then it would bounce them, but invalid mailboxes it would just swallow the mail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a regular expression.

The following pattern tests for any e-mail address ending in a top-level domain like .com, .org, .net, .biz etc.

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum)\b
```

You can use the [preg_match function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) in PHP, pass this as the pattern, and just change the list of top-level domains you want to accept at the end.  If the function returns 0, the address didn't validate, if it returns 1, it did match.

Regex source: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

preg_match: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

jQuery also has a [validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate) with built-in patterns for validating e-mail addresses, but you'd need to combine this with the server-side validation in PHP for those people that have Javascript disabled.

Validate plugin: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate

Comment: +1 informative, I encourage the OP to read the "Regex source" link.

Comment: that is an awesome answer! thank you andy! i got it working =)

Answer (score -1):

```
if( strpos($_post['email'] , '.edu' ) == true){
....
}
```

NOTE:  the  'name' in the input field of the email address should be 'email'

It is the most simple way out there to check if ".edu" is present in that email