# only edu email address

Tags: php

I want to validate email addresses to make sure they have univeristy edu addresses. For example, for USA only "edu" email holders, for Australia only "edu.au", for Turkey only "edu.tr" etc..

Does anyone have a PHP function that will allow me to do that?

Comment: Search before posting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513902/validate-a-edu-or-ac-email-address

Comment: No, but I am sure you can write one yourself. You just actually have to try.

Comment: Just to throw a spanner in the works: `*.ac.uk` for academic institutions. And `*.sch.uk` for schools. We don't use `edu`.

Answer (score 1):

there is no "function" for that.. you have to come up with your own logic for that.
I'd say start of by validating the email address format via Regex and preg_match or something.

Then after you confirm its a validly formatted email address you can explode it into an array using . as your separator/delimiter. Then search the array created for "edu". Seeing as for every . in the string your gonna get whats inbetween them as a value in an array you don't even need to find the .au, .tr, or whatever else there is. Just a thought. Take it or leave it..